# Update every row with a value from another column from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following example of table content

```
+ Column1 | Column2 | Column3 +
+---------|---------|---------+
+   1     | val.txt |         +
+   2     | test.xls|         +
+   3     | abc.dwg |         +
+   4     | y.txt   |         +
+---------|---------|---------+
```

I want to update `Column3` with information from `Column2`, which means I want to (in this case) extract the extension from `Column2` and put it in `Column3`.

I want the result to look like

```
+ Column1 | Column2 | Column3 +
+---------|---------|---------+
+   1     | val.txt |   .txt  +
+   2     | test.xls|   .xls  +
+   3     | abc.dwg |   .dwg  +
+   4     | y.txt   |   .txt  +
+---------|---------|---------+
```

How to do that with an `UPDATE` statement?

I know how to extract the extension:

```
SUBSTRING(Column2, LEN(Column2)-3, LEN(Column2)) AS Extension
```

Comment: Side comment, but your expression for extracting the extension will fail on all the following filenames: "foo.xlsx", "bar.tar.gz", "baz". I'm not sure if this is intentional.

Comment: For my side, these extensions (mentioned by you) won't be available...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about this:

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET Column3 = SUBSTRING(Column2, LEN(Column2)-3, LEN(Column2))
```

If needed, you can also include a `WHERE` clause to limit the rows being updated, e.g.:

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET Column3 = SUBSTRING(Column2, LEN(Column2)-3, LEN(Column2)) 
WHERE Column3 IS NULL
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 UPDATE dbo.YourTable
    SET Column3 =SUBSTRING(Column2,CHARINDEX('.',Column2,0),(LEN(Column2)-CHARINDEX('.',Column2,0)+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the last 4 characters the simplest way is

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET Column3 = RIGHT(Column2,4);
```

To extract everything to the right of the last dot and so work correctly with file names such as `Foo.designer.cs` you can use

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET    Column3 = '.' + RIGHT(Column2, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('.' + Column2)) - 1)
```